# Firebase React Unit Testing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, unit-testing

I am trying to do unit testing on my React Web app which is using firebase auth, firestore and storage. I am pretty new to this and there aren't much resources I can find online.

I just tried to do a simple true test case but I keep getting a auth-api error. Anyone knows how to solve this? Are there any videos I could see to help me?

Code

```
import * as firebase from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing"

describe("Login Component", () => {
    it("rendered input" , () => {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    })
});
```

Error

```
Test suite failed to run

    FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).

      26 | };
      27 | export const storage = app.storage("gs://sftc-development.appspot.com");
    > 28 | export const auth = app.auth();
         |                         ^
      29 | export default app;

      at createErrorInternal (node_modules/@firebase/auth/src/core/util/assert.ts:128:44)
      at _assert (node_modules/@firebase/auth/src/core/util/assert.ts:153:30)
```

firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import "firebase/compat/firestore"
import "firebase/compat/storage"

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})

const firestore = app.firestore();
export const database = {
    usersRef: firestore.collection('user'),
    portfolioRef: firestore.collection('portfolio'),
    projectTitleRef: firestore.collection('projectTitle'),
    audioRef: firestore.collection('audio'),
    videoRef: firestore.collection('video'),
    imageRef: firestore.collection('image'),
    ascensionRef: firestore.collection('ascensionNumber'),
    regEmailRef: firestore.collection('regEmail')
};
export const storage = app.storage("gs://sftc-development.appspot.com");
export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can't help without seeing the code

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2, as of now my testing code only has the stated above and I am already facing issue. I will add my firebase.js config in for better referencing

Comment: Ok. What do you want to test? The initialized process of the app, firestore, storage, and auth?

Comment: Currently, I want to test the login feature which is Firebase Auth. I guess there is a need to initialise the app and auth before testing?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Hi, Currently, I want to test the login feature which is Firebase Auth. I guess there is a need to initialise the app and auth before testing?